# bpftrace hangs after "Attaching probe" message

Tags: bpf, bpftrace

Hi I am trying to run bpftrace on AlmaLinux with uprobe. For any kind of traced application bpftrace shows "attaching .. probe(s)" and then just hangs. It doesn't work neither with bash as appears below or with simple test application compiled locally. Installing pre-compiled package or building locally doesn't change this behaviour.

```
root@hostname➜  ~ bpftrace  -e 'uprobe:/bin/bash:main { printf("in here\n"); }'
Attaching 1 probe...
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Did you try to strace it to see what is blocking?

Comment: I have this exact issue. @pchaigno what command would I run exactly? I'm new to strace